# Translation of mountain and lake names

Tags: translation

I grew up in Geneva, with a beautiful view of Mont Blanc. 
When I was in university, I hiked up Ben Nevis. 
Now I'm working in Taiwan, and I talked to colleagues this lunchtime about hiking up Yushan and Alishan.

One colleague said "Yu mountain", because "shan" is the Chinese word for mountain. It sounded unusual to translate the name of the mountain. I just call it Yushan.

Likewise, "White mountain" for "Mont Blanc" or "Nevis mountain" for "Ben Nevis" would sound wrong.

So I told my colleagues that mountain names are not translated.

The conversation continued, and we talked about Sun Moon Lake. Obviously that name is translated. So is Lake Geneva, and Lake Constance.

It seems that lake names are translated, but mountain names are not.

Is there any formal rule about this? It can be quite confusing to my friends who are not native speakers.

Comment: Hi peterburk, welcome to English Language and Usage. This is a good question, but can you add other examples or references to support your claim that "lake names are translated, but mountain names are not"? For example, in [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_peaks_by_prominence) list of prominent peaks, it seems that while French, Italian and Spanish names are generally *not* translated, the names of peaks in most other non-Anglophone countries *are* translated. Is there a further pattern to this? Editing your answer will increase your chances of upvotes.

Comment: I'm not aware of any formal rule, though there may be something in various Style Guides. I certainly would find it odd if someone called Ben Nevis, Ben Nevis, but then said it was near Lake Lakey instead of Loch Lochy.

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule in terms of how to call a mountain or lake as they are all proper nouns and the way they are called is different country by country. Only one rule I can think of is you place the definite article before a name of a [mountain range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_range) as in the Rocky mountains (the Rockies), the Alps (mountains), the Andes (mountains), etc.

Usually, you use *Mt.* which is contraction for mount before a name of a big mountain as in Mt. Everest, Mt. Vesuvius, Mr. Olympus, etc.

For small mountains, you usually use the "proper name + mountain". You are right that "shan (**山**)" means a mountain, however, Yushan is the proper name of the mountain and it is better not to call it "Yu Mountain" and the linked Wikipedia article on [Yushan (mountain)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yushan_(mountain)) seems to support this.

However, for 富士**山** (literally Fuji Mountain), it is not called Fujishan mountain or Fuji mountain. It is called [Mt. Fuji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Fuji) as it has the highest mountain peak in Japan.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider that some named mountains are popular names from explorers and the like. Consider **Mount Everest**, named **Sagarmāthā** in Nepali, and **Chomolungma** in Tibetan.

From Wikipedia:

In 1865, Everest was given its official English name by the Royal Geographical Society, upon a recommendation by Andrew Waugh, the British Surveyor General of India. As there appeared to be several different local names, Waugh chose to name the mountain after his predecessor in the post, Sir George Everest, despite George Everest's objections.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest